# How to access Clarion Tables from Java

Tags: java, database, clarion

I have this client with this system coded in `Clarion`. He is needing an webservice in `Java` to public some `API`s from their system.

Does anyone know the best approach to access and modify any given clarion table ( `.dat` file) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Capesoft's Nettalk or Clarion Handy Tools to create a SOAP server that accesses .dat, .tps or any other data Clarion is capable of accessing. The examples provided make it quite simple and these servers perform well.